# TweetNaCl gives wrong encoding when trying to decrypt

Tags: javascript, cryptography, nacl-cryptography

I'm trying to get [TweetNaCl.js](https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js) working.

My problem is that when I decrypt the data, the output is encoded wrong.

Encrypted data:

```
你好，世界
```

Decrypted data:

```
ä½ å¥½ï¼ä¸ç
```

Here is my decryption function:

```
Crypto.decrypt = function(key, nonce, ciphertext) {
  var message, box;
  try {
    key = nacl.util.decodeBase64(key);
    nonce = nacl.util.decodeBase64(nonce);
  } catch(ex) {
    alert('Error decoding');
    return;
  }
  try {
    box = nacl.util.decodeBase64(ciphertext);
  } catch(ex) {
    alert('Cannot decode box');
    return;
  }
  message = nacl.secretbox.open(box, nonce, key);
  if (message === false) {
    alert('Failed to decrypt');
    return;
  }
  try {
    message = nacl.util.encodeUTF8(message);
    console.log(message);
  } catch(ex) {
    alert('Cannot decode decrypted message to string');
    return;
  }
  return message;
}
```

So if I encrypt the text `你好，世界` with key `noIIyNy5sH61LdrmChTHW24qAFbNOv1brq9QnR9vsoE=` and with nonce `XeB7tdP8CB8Y2/aybsK498gCRJz469yM` the encrypted text will be `iFcrAeRqrnhu67zZupYO23UmEC0kl21Dcuo6b33gsg==`.

So now when I decrypt:

```
Crypto.decrypt('noIIyNy5sH61LdrmChTHW24qAFbNOv1brq9QnR9vsoE=', 'XeB7tdP8CB8Y2/aybsK498gCRJz469yM', 'iFcrAeRqrnhu67zZupYO23UmEC0kl21Dcuo6b33gsg==');
```

Output: `ä½ å¥½ï¼ä¸ç` instead of the original input `你好，世界`.

Output is working perfectly fine in this example page: https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/secretbox but somehow my decryption function gives wrong encoding.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I made a fiddle, where the encoding is working fine... My program has a bug somewhere else then it seems.  https://jsfiddle.net/user88593902/t78kb92n/

Comment: Looks like character set encoding issue. You can debug by printing the output to the console before the line  :     message = nacl.util.encodeUTF8(message);.

Comment: Message before that line is a Uint8Array containing random bytes.

Comment: I made a fiddle and there the encoding is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/user88593902/t78kb92n/ It's just my app bugs somewhere else... no idea where.

Comment: You can try enc/dec with a non multi byte character string , say "TESTSTRING" to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Roshith It seems to work fine with a-Z0-9 characters. But for example character `ó` encodes to `Ã³` and character `ä` encodes to `Ã¤`. I have no idea why it does that.

Comment: Right. Now in which environment the issue occurs ? You mentioned your app ? what sort of app is it ? It could be a limitation /issue with the way the app prints out multi byte characters.

Comment: @Roshith It's LAMP environment. It fetches the encrypted data from mysql with ajax, then just puts it to the html dom. Mysql is working with utf8mb4_general_ci. Ajax is fetched with JSON, server prints JSON with UTF-8. HTML file has UTF-8 charset in the head element.

Comment: Okay wth. My document encoding is somehow messed up. Even when the server serves the http document in UTF-8 and I have HTML chartset set to UTF-8... weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[he.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) library was conflicting with the TweetNaCl library. Removing it and it started to work like it should.

Comment: Cool. May there was double encoding.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the help anyways!